# How do I get Bibilioteca running on Wine?

Tags: 11.10, wine

I've got a problem with Wine. I installed the package I found in the Ubuntu Software Center but it doesn't work with Biblioteca PC (that is a German dictionary). I have Ubuntu 11.10 and it worked fine with Ubuntu 11.04.

Do I need to install something else, or is there any other way to get the program running under Wine?

Comment: you really havent added any detail - please look at running your application from the command line - any errors?  What version of wine have you installed?  For those of us not familiar with the "german dictionary" can you add a weblink?  Are you using 32bit or 64bit?  Have you consulted the winehq.org database?

Comment: I've installed wine 1.3, winetricks, and Microsoft windows compatibility layer. I installed Biblioteca PC but when i try to run it, it appears and one second later disappears! Biblioteca pc is a CD dictionary of a paper dictionary! you can install the exe. file from the CD and than use the program on your computer (http://biblioteca-pc.software.informer.com/). I have Ubuntu 11.10 32bit

Comment: Hi there - should say Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Since this is a question and answer site - please re-edit your question with any additional information you have.  Important stuff in comments tend to get lost or not read especially if there is a lot of comments.  Please look at my questions and add replies to everything in your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В Ubuntu 11.04 программа работала нормально(стояло Wine1.3).После обновления до Ubuntu 11.10 и обновления Wine1.3 до Wine1.3.31 - появились проблемы.Убрал Wine1.3.31 и поставил Wine1.2 - всё заработало как и в Ubuntu 11.04.Буду рад,если это поможет.

Google Translate:

In Ubuntu 11.04 program worked just fine (standing Wine1.3). After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 and upgrade to Wine1.3 Wine1.3.31 - appeared problemy.Ubral Wine1.3.31 and put Wine1.2 - it worked as well in Ubuntu 11.04.Budu happy if it helps.

Comment: what???i don't understand!!!